# " Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." when trying to create object record

Tags: apex, javascript, sobject, database, js

I am trying to insert record in Salesforce after a button click but I receive this error when clicking on the button. Below are provided my JS and apex class for the handling of this operation. No record is created and neither the error or success message is printed.

**detailsComponent.js**

```
import createVisit from '@salesforce/apex/VisitsController.createVisit';
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';


export default class DetailsComponent extends LightningElement {

    @track visitDate;
    @track visitTime;
    @track patientName;
    @track patientEmail;
    @track visitDescription;


    changeHandler(event){
        const name = event.target.name;
        let value = name.value;
       
        if(name==='dateDetail'){
            this.visitDate=value;
        }else if(name==='timeDetail'){
            this.visitTime=value;
        }else if(name==='nameDetail'){
            this.patientName=value;
        }else if(name==='emailDetail'){
            this.patientEmail=value;
        }else if(name==='descriptionDetail'){
            this.visitDescription=value;
        }
    }


    createHandler(){
       if(this.visitDate =! null && this.visitTime !=null && this.patientEmail != null){
           const visit = {
               visitDate : this.visitDate,
                visitTime : this.visitTime,
                visitDescription : this.visitDescription,
                patientName : this.patientName,
                patientEmail : this.patientEmail
           }

           createVisit({ payload : JSON.stringify(visit)}).then(response => {
                console.log(('Item inserted sucessfully'))
           }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Error in creating visit' + error)
           });
       }
    }



}
```

**VisitsController.cls**

```
public with sharing class VisitsController {
   
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createVisit(String payload) {
      Visit payloadObject = (Visit) JSON.deserialize(payload, Visit.class);
  
      SObject visit = (Sobject) Type.forName('Visit__c').newInstance();
      visit.put('Date__c', payloadObject.visitDate);
      visit.put('Time__c', payloadObject.visitTime);
      visit.put('Patient_Email__c', payloadObject.patientEmail);
      visit.put('Patient_Name__c', payloadObject.patientName);
      visit.put('Description__c', payloadObject.visitDescription);
  
      insert visit;
  
      return String.valueOf(visit.Id);
    }



    class Visit{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Date visitDate;

        @AuraEnabled
        public Time visitTime;

        
        @AuraEnabled
        public String patientEmail;
        
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public String patientName;

        @AuraEnabled
        public String visitDescription;


    }
}
```

I have done all the neccessary permset and force:source push operations. The object is created. The object fields and api name can be seen below. [image]

[image]

**Edit:**
I know there is a chance that this issue is not related to the classes itself, but maybe you can help me with finding the cause in order to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that:

```
let value = name.value;
```

Should be:

```
let value = event.target.value;
```

I don't see any other reason why this code should necessarily fail, though I haven't seen this error before.

---

You can reduce your code to just:

```
public with sharing class VisitsController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static Id createVisit(Visit__c record) {
        insert record;
        return record.Id;
    }
}
```

---

```
import createVisit from '@salesforce/apex/VisitsController.createVisit';
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class DetailsComponent extends LightningElement {
    visitDate;
    visitTime;
    patientName;
    patientEmail;
    visitDescription;

    changeHandler(event) {
        this[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    }

    async createHandler() {
        try {
            if (this.visitDate && this.visitTime && this.patientEmail) {
                let visitId = await createVisit({
                    record: {
                        sobjectType: 'Visit__c',
                        Date__c: this.visitDate,
                        Time__c: this.visitTime,
                        Patient_Email__c: this.patientEmail,
                        Patient_Name__c: this.patientName,
                        Description__c: this.visitDescription,
                    },
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error creating visit: ', e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code, and, while it is more well-structured, it still gives the same error. I tried to contact from my JS file to the Apex class through an empty function just to see if the problem is related to my data operations or the connection itself, and I got this error when I tried to contact the aura enabled apex method:  "{"status":500,"body":{"message":"error retrieving aura config: unauthenticated"},"headers":{}}" maybe it gives you some more info into the error.

Comment: @adidascoder is this in a community? Are you sure you're logged in?

Comment: Hello again! So i have been struggling with this problem for over a week now. I tried giving permission sets to my CLI, I tried changing many things and I have narrowed it down to a more specific error. Good news is, the POST request gets sent with the sObject information, it just encounters the same error again when the post is sent. When I try to perform a SELECT SOQL query from the VS code, it does perform well. I am still not sure what the error points to since I found no info online about this error. But maybe there is a little bit more info on where to search for my error.

Comment: @adidascoder I can try to replicate it, but I'm not sure what else I can do. Have you tried Technical Support?

Comment: Hi! I finally resolved the issue. It was related to my localserver ports. The port did not allow api requests from my browser port. Maybe a security measure. How I resolved it was by installing the allow CORS plugin which made cross port communication possible and allowed my requests to go through. Again, thank you for your help!